# Magento Command Run Using .bat file

Tags: magento2.3, cron, command-line

> **How to Use Magento 2 CMD Command using the .bat file**

```
 I am Wrtting this Commands but still it is not working
```

```
D:\xampp7.2\php\php.exe D:\xampp7.2\htdocs\m232\bin\magento cron:run
D:\xampp7.2\php\php.exe D:\xampp7.2\htdocs\m232\app\code\vednor\module_name\cron\test.php
D:\xampp7.2\php\php.exe D:\xampp7.2\htdocs\m232\bin\magento setup:cron:run
```

I Want the run Cron Job File Using .bat.

Comment: Remove 'setup:' from line 3

Comment: Still it is not working !

Comment: use Follow line in place of 3rd line. 
D:\xampp7.2\php\php.exe D:\xampp7.2\htdocs\m232\php -d memory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:cron:run

Comment: Thanks, But i Alreay Solved this issue it occur with my windows system so i have to setup cron into my windows